# How to add my kernel driver .kext to my application myapp.app while making MAC installer through package software

Tags: macos, package, kernel-extension, pkg-file

I am new to MAC  territory. I have made an .app and tested it and works fine.

Problems:
1) I created the .pkg using Package software for my app it is installing in APPLICATION Folder and works fine.        But if i add my .kext(kernal) in the Library/Extension folder is not installing through the Inastaller (package).

I have followed this guide step by step. 
http://s.sudre.free.fr/Software/documentation/Packages/en/index.html

Software used
http://s.sudre.free.fr/Software/Packages/about.html

Note:- I need to install my .kext in system/Library/Extension path

2) I have load different languages in my installed (.pkg) , In preview option of language changing is present, when i select different language and create installer(.pkg ) all again come in english.

Comment: You'll need to be a bit more specific. A few things to note: 1. As of OSX 10.11 (El Capitan) you can't install to /System/Library/Extensions/ - you must use /Library/Extensions/ (use /System/Library/Extensions for 10.8 or earlier, but it technically still works for 10.9 and 10.10 too). You need elevated privileges to write to /Library/Extensions/ - is your installer asking for an admin password? 3. Be more specific about how you add the kext to your installer.

Comment: i am using MAC OS x 10.10 and yeah do it ask for admin password and i have provided it. it execute successfully . but only app will get installed not the .kext ...in ( /Library/Extensions/)

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you have to sign your kext. Since OS X bring SIP, kext without sign will not accept. check this url [Kernel Extensions](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Conceptual/System_Integrity_Protection_Guide/KernelExtensions/KernelExtensions.html)

EDIT:
There is another reason that your kext don't installed, check your package name, Sudre said it in the [docs](http://s.sudre.free.fr/Software/documentation/Packages/en/Package_Settings_Customization.html#1)

> When you work on a raw package project, the name of the package is defined by the name of the project. See Configuring a project for more information.

So I suggest you to check you project name, if is the same as your package name.
If not, create a new project in packages, set the same name as project. Hope it will work!

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes